# JPA query - add matched id to list

Tags: java, querydsl

How can I retrieve the matched id from this query and add it to the list at the bottom of the query? Currently I get a list with results, but I have no idea with what ID in the parameter they were matched.

See comments in code.

P.S. This is not the full query, I made it smaller so its easier to read.

```
@Override
public List<EventDTO> getTotalEventByFilter(List<Long> idList){
    QActivity subActivity = new QActivity("subActivity");
    QUser subUser = new QUser("subUser");
    QAttendancelist subAttendancelist = new QAttendancelist("subAttendancelist");

    ListSubQuery<Long> allUserAtEvent = new JPASubQuery().from(qUser)
        .innerJoin(qUser.attendancelist, qAttendancelist)
        .innerJoin(qAttendancelist.activity, qActivity)
        .where(qActivity.id.in(idList)) //<--- I need to know with what ID it matched to and add that ID to the list at the bottom of the code
        .where(qAttendancelist.present.isTrue())
        .list(user.id);

    ListSubQuery<LocalDate> eventDate = new JPASubQuery().from(qActivity)
        .where(qActivity.id.in(idList))
        .list(qActivity.activityDate);

     List<EventDTO> query = from(qUser)
        .innerJoin(qUser.attendancelist, qAttendancelist)
        .innerJoin(qAttendancelist.activity, qActivity)
        .leftJoin(qActivity.activityLocation, qActivityLocation)
        .where(user.id.in(allUserAtEvent))
        .where(qActivity.id.notIn(idList))
        .where(qAttendancelist.present.isTrue())
        .where(qActivity.activityDate.gtAll(eventDate)) 
        .groupBy(qActivity.name, qActivityLocation.name, qActivity.activityDate)
        .orderBy(user.id.desc())
        .list(new QEventDTO(qActivity.id, qActivity.name, qActivityLocation.name, //the matched ID));

return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity class (represented in this query by the qActivity object) has a property called "id", that's what the parameter is matched to.

Comment: It is matched to an id that is in the idList. So if the list has 3 id's and the query returns 15 results, out of those 15 I need to know which results belong to id#1, which results belong to id#2 etc. I have edited the name of the parameter to make it easier to understand